# Stacked Heat Map in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I would like to create a stacked heatmap. basically i have sub categories, I would want to show in a Heatmap. 
After searching I figured it is not possible to do.

So I am wondering if it is possible to create a stacked heatmap instead where sub categories would be stacked on top to make a category. A mixture of bar chart and heat map.

Please see the fiddle .. As a an example I tried to attain the objective with multiple series. As you can notice if the series have same values they just sit on top of each other. Is there a better way to visualize such a data ?

Heatmap take x,y,value. If a data had x,y,value AND Z .. What would be the best way to visualize in highcharts?

Thanks..

Comment: fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/1958v30p/

Comment: Could you elaborate with a visualization (image) of what you're trying to achieve? It's hard to imagine how it should look like.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel something like this https://jsfiddle.net/bdtyr4zj/ So I have a way to sub categorize and also show value by color

Comment: It's still not enough for me to understand your idea. Perhaps it will be better to create layers that can present a "z" value on a heatmap. Check this example where years are layers (z value): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u1rst3Lf/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks a lot for the example. Yes that is somewhat close to my idea. Layers is a possibility. But i want to make all data visible .. without a toggle button (z-layer select) i mean. if I can't find a way to display all data at once. I might have to resort to this layering solution.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel , since its a lot of data I am using data module to load heatmap. http://jsfiddle.net/6k17dojn/ I notice that when colorAxis is visible the series is not shown in legend, when i put it to false then it is visible. colorAxis: {showInLegend: false} Would you know a way to show both the coloraxis and the series in legend ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the current implementation doesn't support both color axis and series in legend. Perhaps the logic will be changed in the future releases of Highcharts.